# This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used

Tags: flutter, recursion, dart

I have created a new method to use it at as recursion i am creating function to get refresh token backe from API server

```
  void postLogin(LoginRequest loginRequest) async {
    _postStream.sink.add(Result<String>.loading("Loading"));
    try {
      final response = await client.post('$BASE_URL\/$LOGIN_URL', headers: customHeader, body: json.encode(loginRequest));
      print(response.body.toString());
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        _postStream.sink.add(Result<LoginResponse>.success(
            LoginResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body))));
      } else if(response.statusCode == 401) {
           getAuthUpadate(postLogin(loginRequest));//error is showing at this place
      }
      else{
        _postStream.sink.add(Result.error(REQUEST_ERROR));

      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      _postStream.sink.add(Result.error(INTERNET_ERROR));
    }
  }
//////////////
```

i tried this function inside function in flutter it saying
void cant be allowed

```
  getAuthUpadate(Function function()) async {
    try{
      final response = await client.post('$BASE_URL\/NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN_PATH', headers: customHeader,body:json.encode('RefreshToken'));
      //get the refreshToken from response
      String accessToken = response.body.toString();
      //store this access token to the data
      function();
    }
    catch (error){

    }
  }
```

Comment: `getAuthUpadate` expects a *function* that takes no arguments.  You would need to do something like `getAuthUpadate(() => postLogin(loginRequest))`.

Answer (score 1):

I could give you an idea about this issue.

 You are just calling the function which has return value `void` and passing it as a parameter to the function `getAuthUpdate`. 

 You can try something like this,

```
getAuthUpadate(Function function, LoginRequest loginRequest) async { }
```

and in the `postLogin` method, you could try something like this,

```
else if(response.statusCode == 401) {
     getAuthUpadate(postLogin, loginRequest);  // Just pass Reference as parameter! 
}
```

finally, the iteration part of `getAuthUpdate` method,

```
 try{
      final response = await client.post('$BASE_URL\/NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN_PATH', headers: customHeader,body:json.encode('RefreshToken'));
      //get the refreshToken from response
      String accessToken = response.body.toString();
      //store this access token to the data
      function(loginRequest);
  }
  catch (error){

  }
```

Hope that works!

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me when I passed in a `void` in a callback method (e.g. calling `function()` when function is declared to be `void function() { ... }`.

For example:

```dart
IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          MdiIcons.plusCircle,
        ),
        onPressed: _navigateToJoinQuizScreen()); // <--- Wrong, should just be _navigateToJoinQuizScreen
```